# Stomach Vacuum/Cat vomit: next step for more permanent results

Tags: core

I'm doing the cat vomit exercise for more than one year now (I do 10 reps of 16s everyday, my waistline goes from 78 cms to 72 cms when I do the stomach vacuum vertically).

I look for more 'permanent' results, my stomach looks very forward (while I only have 5% of BF), isn't there 'harder'/more advanced exercises to keep increasing my transverse abdominis' strength?

Comment: Well this sent me down the cat vomit google wormhole....

Comment: Inhale siringes... attach a tube to a siringe and move the siringe by sucking in the air through the tube.  Or suck your stomach out with a real vacuum while trying to resist it

Comment: You might want to add some conventional ab work, too (sit-ups, crunches, leg lifts, bicycle kicks). This *cat vomit exercise* is just 1 exercise. It can't do everything.

Answer (score 1):

Add exercise to strengthen your lower back to get it straigther and add some conventional ab exercise, if possible add weigth